# What does (array) $variable mean in php

Tags: php, casting

I'v recently came accross a problem with some code as shown below:

```
    $key = "upload_8_fid_aids.tmp";
    public function to_key($key) {

        $s = $this->table;//$s = kv
        foreach((array)$key as $k=>$v) {
            $s .= '-'.$this->primarykey[$k].'-'.$v;
        }
        return $s;
    }
```

There's a (array)$key signature out there in the foreach loop,the first thing I'm stucking in is the "array" that prefixed with the variabls $k,what does this mean?The very first idea that hit upon me is that it converts the $k to an array,though,the variable $k is a string,is it plausible to convert string to array in php?I think it is unreasonable.So what does that array mean?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the $key is an object and they are converting it to an Array!!

Comment: @TomPHP $k is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you cast a string to an array in PHP it becomes an array with the string pushed to it.

[Example](http://3v4l.org/YQ9oA):

```
$test = "This is a string!";
print_r((array) $test);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is a string!
)
```

That said I find the code strange, I don't see the need for the loop, it could just be:

```
$key = "upload_8_fid_aids.tmp";

public function to_key($key) {
    $s = $this->table; //$s = kv
    $s .= '-' . $this->primarykey[0] . '-' . $key;
    return $s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any type enclosed in parentheses is telling PHP to cast the following thing to that type.

In this case, it's a cheap way to avoid having to check `if( is_array($key))`, by just forcing it to be one.

Answer (score 0):

Converting an object to an array:

```
 <?php
        /*** create an object ***/
        $obj = new stdClass;
        $obj->foo = 'foo';
        $obj->bar = 'bar';
        $obj->baz = 'baz';

        /*** cast the object ***/
        $array = (array) $obj;

        /*** show the results ***/
        print_r( $array );
    ?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => foo
    [bar] => bar
    [baz] => baz
)
```